# Populate a drop down in twig based on data in the database

Tags: php, function, twig

OK what I am trying to do is populate a drop down in a twig view.  The options would be numbers 1-12 and 14-17.  I need to show only the numbers not active in the database.  I am very new to php so I may be trying to do this all wrong.  In twig I was trying to do a:

```
{% if app.user.usernumber1 %}
// if returned true leave blank
{$ else $}
<option value"1">1</option>
{% endif %}
```

I am sure there is a way to use a for loop of some kind to keep from having to wright the code for each number but for now I am just wanting to make it work.  usernumber1 would be a function to test if the number is active. Here is what I was trying.

```
<?php

namespace Rocmnd\user;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class user extends Eloquent
{
protected $table = 'user';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'user_first_name',
    'user_last_name',
    'active'


];

public function usernumber1() 
{
    $usernum = $this->user
                ->where('user_id', 1) 
                ->where('active', true)
                ->first();

    return (bool) $usernum->count();

}
```

Here is where I have am having problems.  I tried to echo out the function and I get a Call to a member function where() on null. when I move the code to the index page it works fine like this.

```
 echo ($app->user
         ->where('user_id', 1)
         ->where('active', true)
         ->first());
```

Where am i going wrong when I put this into the function?

Comment: The best way to populate with twig are loops, all documented here : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It helped for the ones i could fully understand I'm sure as i use it more i will start to understand them more. For what I am trying to do I guess I did not explain clear enough sorry.  My user table has a column of user_id this is not the primary key.  As a use is added they will be assigned a user_id 1-17 excluding 13.  when a user becomes inactive it will open that user_id up.  So if i try to run a "not active" it can return a false true right?

Comment: If I am understanding this right I need a {for i in 1..17} and a {for user in users}.  Then I would need to compare them {for user_id == {{i}} if user.active} to return a true.  Then use a else for the false and return the {{i}} as the option.  then I would need to compare the {{i}} to see if it == 13 and exclude it.  I have no idea how to all that together.  @felipsmartins